# SVG fill with use tag

Tags: css, svg, shadow-dom

I'm trying to change the color of an SVG displayed on different pages using `<svg id="logo-svg"><use xlink:href="#kmc-logo"></use></svg>`.

The methods I'm trying are here: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/.

This is the SVG `symbol` I'm pulling in (shortened to relevant pieces):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="kmc-logo" viewBox="0 0 151 151">
        <g id="logo">
            <g id="outer-circle">
                <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11.51 ..."/>
            </g>
            <g id="ceramics">
                <path stroke="none" d="M39.47 ..."/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I have this style in my stylesheet:

```
#masthead > .content-width .site-branding .logo--white a #logo-svg {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

The `stroke` color here is working fine for the `#outer-circle` in the shadow-dom'd SVG above, but the fill isn't working on the path inside `#ceramics`.

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I've updated this question after discovering that the issue isn't with css specificity, but rather with styling elements inside shadow-dom svgs.

Comment: Does the visited link appear as `#fff`, and your question is "Why is the `a:visited` not crossed out"? Or does the visited link color actually appear as `#343533`? If it's the latter, we'll need a demo that reproduces the issue. I've [copy+pasted your code](https://jsfiddle.net/szrpagwe/), and while the `a:visited` is still listed, the `#masthead > .content-width .site-branding h1 a:visited` shows the proper color.

Comment: @TylerRoper, I've added some relevant info to my question. It concerns use of SVG in the shadow-DOM. Sorry I didn't specify this at first.

Comment: I think we'll need a [mcve] here if we're to help. How many browsers have you tried?

Comment: I've added the last bit of relevant code: the nested svg that I'm trying to style. It's the `fill` attribute of `#ceramics path` that's giving me trouble. I've tried setting it explicitly, which works, but I need to be able to change the color under different circumstances. And I've tried `fill="currentColor"`, but this pulls the `#343533` color from the beginning of my question.

Comment: I've updated my question after discovering the more specific problem I'm having: coloring/styling elements inside an svg displayed using a `use` tag.

Comment: I ended up figuring out that the `* { transition: all .2s ease; }` that I had put in at a different time was preventing the fill style from applying to this svg. Why? How? I'm not sure. But I took it out and all is working as expected now. Thanks to everyone who took the time to check it out! Sorry for the diversion!

Answer (score 6):

In fact, the solution is very simple for you. Just change everywhere in the **svg** file from `fill = "none"` to `fill = "currentColor"`.
In this case, all the **fill** properties inside the **svg** element inherit the *color* from the parent element that wraps it. Then add color property to parent element.

```css
.logo-svg {
    color: #fff;
}

.logo-svg--yellow {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo-svg">
  <use href="#some-svg" xlink:href="#some-svg" />
</svg>

<svg class="logo-svg--yellow">
  <use href="#some-svg" xlink:href="#some-svg" />
</svg>

<svg id="some-svg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Thanks to your question and answer above, I solved my problem by making the changes I described.

**UPD**. According to the new rules,

> instead of xlink:href you should use [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)

Comment: I was having a lot of weird behaviours on Chrome and this helped me. Now I can change the color like any font. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: fill="none" was not allowing to update svg color from parent. This helped, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

What you've done seems okay.  I've reproduced it roughly below.
Perhaps this will help you.

If your "ceramics" path is not showing, then there might be something wrong with it.  But we would need to see it.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.logo--white #logo-svg {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #fff;
}

.logo--yellow #logo-svg {
    fill: #ff0;
    stroke: #ff0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="kmc-logo" viewBox="0 0 151 151">
    <g id="logo">
      <g id="outer-circle">
        <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
              stroke-width="10" 
              d="M 25,25 L 25,125"/>
      </g>
      <g id="ceramics">
        <path stroke="none"
              d="M 100,25 A 50,50 0 0 0 100,125 A 50,50 0 0 0 100,25 Z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="logo--white" viewBox="0 0 151 151">
  <svg id="logo-svg"><use xlink:href="#kmc-logo"></use></svg>
</div>

<div class="logo--yellow" viewBox="0 0 151 151">
  <svg id="logo-svg"><use xlink:href="#kmc-logo"></use></svg>
</div>
```